# How to add two lines in the center of a button

Tags: html, css, button

There is a button with a border: 3px solid #E82929; what technology can be used to add additional lines like in the photo?

[image]

```css
.btn {
  position: relative;
  width: 362px;
  height: 71px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #000000;
  border: 3px solid #E82929;
  font-family: 'Flamenco';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Забронировать столик</button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use gradient

```css
.btn {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 3px solid #E82929;
  font-family: 'Flamenco';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #E82929 40px,#0000 0 calc(100% - 40px), #E82929 0) 50%/100% 3px no-repeat;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Забронировать столик</button>
```

Comment: This is the way - hard to read but yeah... Is the trailing 0 on `#0000` supposed to be transparency?

Comment: @mplungjan yes, it's the 4-hex values that is the shorthand of the 8-hex value so the last one is for transparency

Comment: The prettier does not like it here...

Answer (score 3):

You do not need extra markup, because it can be done with the [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) and [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) pseudo elements.

Assuming your 2 lines at the left and right should have a width of `30px` and a left and right padding of `10px`, you could add this to your already existing CSS:

```css
.btn {
  position: relative;
  width: 362px;
  height: 71px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #000000;
  border: 3px solid #E82929;
  font-family: 'Flamenco';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* extra code comes here */
.btn {
  padding: 0 40px; /* 30px line width + 10px padding */
}

.btn::before,
.btn::after {
  background-color: #E82929; /* border color */
  content: ''; /* content is mandatory for the element to show up */
  height: 3px; /* 3px border width */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; /* 50% from the top */
  transform: translateY(-50%); /* half of its height back to the top */
  width: 30px; /* 30px line width */
}

.btn::before {
  left: 0;
}

.btn::after {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Забронировать столик</button>
```

Change the width and padding according to your needs.

What it does: It adds the [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) and [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) pseudo elements with no text content on the left and right and positions them vertically centered.

If you have any questions regarding details, feel free to ask.

Comment: nice attempt but not practicable as it way to difficault. It lack simplicity as a good solution. Temani solved this with a single property